# Error while creating thumbnails in PHP

Tags: php, thumbnails

This is my code for creating thumbnails. Here I'm attempting to check if the thumbnail already exists. If it does it's displayed directly. Else the thumbnail is created and then displayed.

```
<a class="adiimage" rel="colorbox" title=" " href="new/artists/data/single_image.php?imageid=<?php echo $rowa_image['product_image_id']; ?>">
            <!--<img src="new/images/upload/<?php echo $image; ?>"  alt="" border="0" />-->
        <?php
                $addr = $_SERVER['HOME'];
                echo '<script> alert("'.$addr.'"); </script>';
                /*$pathToImages = "../new/images/upload/";
                $pathToThumbs = "../new/images/upload/thumbs/";*/
                $pathToImages = "../new/images/upload/";
                $pathToThumbs = "../new/images/upload/thumbs/";
                $thumbWidth = 100;
                $filename = $pathToThumbs . $image;
                //check if thumbnail exists
                if(file_exists($filename)){ 
                    //display thumbnail
                ?>
                    <img src="<?php echo $filename; ?>"  alt="" border="0" />
                <?php
                }
                else{
                    //create thumbnail
                    createThumbs($pathToImages, $pathToThumbs, $thumbWidth, $image);
                    //createThumbs("new/images/upload/","new/images/upload/thumbs/",100);
                ?>
                    <img src="<?php echo $filename; ?>"  alt="" border="0" />
                <?php
                }
            } 
        ?>
        </a>
         <!--</div>-->
    </li>
<?php  }   }   } ?>
</ul>
</div>


<?php 

//thumbnail creation 
function createThumbs( $pathToImages, $pathToThumbs, $thumbWidth, $image ) 
{
// open the directory
//$dir = opendir( $pathToImages );
$dir = fopen($pathToImages, "rw");
/* read the source image */
$file = $pathToImages . $image;
//echo '<script> alert("'.$file.'"); </script>';
$source_image = imagecreatefromjpeg($pathToImages);
//$source_image = imagecreatefromjpeg( "{$pathToImages}{$image}" );

$width = imagesx($source_image);
$height = imagesy($source_image);

/* find the "desired height" of this thumbnail, relative to the desired width  */
$desired_height = floor($height * ($thumbWidth / $width));

/* create a new, "virtual" image */
$virtual_image = imagecreatetruecolor($thumbWidth, $desired_height);

/* copy source image at a resized size */
imagecopyresampled($virtual_image, $source_image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $thumbWidth, $desired_height, $width, $height);

/* create the physical thumbnail image to its destination */
//imagejpeg($virtual_image, $pathToThumbs);
imagejpeg($virtual_image, "{$pathToThumbs}{$image}");
}
?>
```

The above code is giving me the following error which I don't know how to solve. I think that the file path is the issue. But I'm not sure what's exactly wrong.

```
Warning: fopen(../new/images/upload/) [
function.fopen
]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in  /home/artistiv/public_html/new/publicprofile/artist_image.php on line 107

Warning: imagecreatefromjpeg(../new/images/upload/) [
function.imagecreatefromjpeg
]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/artistiv/public_html/new/publicprofile/artist_image.php on line 111

Warning: imagesx() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /home/artistiv/public_html/new/publicprofile/artist_image.php on line 114

Warning: imagesy() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /home/artistiv/public_html/new/publicprofile/artist_image.php on line 115

Warning: Division by zero in /home/artistiv/public_html/new/publicprofile/artist_image.php on line 118

Warning: imagecreatetruecolor() [
function.imagecreatetruecolor
]: Invalid image dimensions in /home/artistiv/public_html/new/publicprofile/artist_image.php on line 121

Warning: imagecopyresampled() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /home/artistiv/public_html/new/publicprofile/artist_image.php on line 124

Warning: imagejpeg() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in     /home/artistiv/public_html/new/publicprofile/artist_image.php on line 128
```

When I used opendir function too it gave me the following error:

```
function.imagecreatefromjpeg
]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/artistiv/public_html/new/publicprofile/artist_image.php on line 110
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17613440/rename-nama-in-upload-zf2-aws-s3/20052493#20052493

Answer (score 1):

The error is self-explanatory:

- You are at `/home/artistiv/public_html/new/publicprofile/artist_image.php`
- You ask to open `../new/images/upload/` which equals to `/home/artistiv/public_html/new/new/images/upload/`
- There's no such file or directory

You're also using the `rw` flags—I cannot find them in the [list of possible modes](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php):

- `r` alone is *Open for reading only*
- `w` alone is *Open for writing only*

How could PHP do both things at the same time?

Comment: ok i made the following corrections..  `$pathToImages = "../images/upload/";$pathToThumbs = "../images/upload/thumbs/";` and in the createthumbs method `$dir = opendir( $pathToImages );`... yet it gives me the error **Warning: imagecreatefromjpeg(../images/upload/2145772001IMG_9999_241%20copy.JPG) [
function.imagecreatefromjpeg
]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/artistiv/public_html/new/publicprofile/artist_image.php on line 111**

Comment: Now you know what "No such file or directory" means you shouldn't have any problem fixing that.

Answer (score 0):

Your filepath seems to be /home/artistiv/public_html/new/publicprofile/

There for your Path variables should be set like this:

$pathToImages = "../images/upload/";
$pathToThumbs = "../images/upload/thumbs/";

or

$pathToImages = "../../new/images/upload/";
$pathToThumbs = "../../new/images/upload/thumbs/";

Comment: i changed the file path and changed the code `$dir = fopen($pathToImages, "w");` to `$dir = opendir( $pathToImages );`. i get the error/ warning *Warning: imagecreatefromjpeg(../images/upload/2145772001IMG_9999_241%20copy.JPG) [ function.imagecreatefromjpeg ]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/artistiv/public_html/new/publicprofile/artist_image.php on line 111*

Comment: Have you checked the Path? Does the file exist? Your Filepath seems to miss a slash: ../images/upload/2145772001/IMG_9999_241%20copy.JPG - only a guess.